# List rackspace CDN-enabled containers with php-opencloud

Tags: rackspace, php-opencloud

The documentation states

> To list CDN-only containers, follow the same operation for Storage which lists all containers. The only difference is which service object you execute the method on.

But what is the right service object. I tried:

```
$service = objectStoreService('cloudFiles', $region);
$service = objectStoreCDNService('cloudFilesCDN', $region);
$service = objectStoreCDNService('cloudFiles', $region);
$service = objectStoreService('cloudFilesCDN', $region);
```

And `$containers = $service->listContainers()` or `$containers->listContainers(array('enabled_only' => TRUE))` with all of the above to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already noticed, you need to provide the `enabled_only` query parameter in order to retrieve CDN-enabled containers.

You're going wrong because your `true` is being converted to `1` in the URL. This is a natural boolean conversion. The API, however, seems to be expecting a string. Changing it to:

```
$containers = $service->listContainers(array(
   'enabled_only' => 'true'
));
```

should work.

---

What happens if you perform the operation on the CDN service:

```
$containers = $service->getCdnService()->listContainers();
```

Comment: @user3262718 I've edited the original answer - does the above work for you?

Comment: Yes this works. But I think this also list private containers or something cause I see more containers in the list.

Comment: @user3262718 The above will list CDN-enabled containers only for a given region.